PowerAutomate Flow Help - Update a list from two different Arrays
Would anyone be able to assist me in figuring out the logic for this flow in power automate?
I am trying to parse emails and I got to the point of pulling the data I want out and holding it in 2 arrays.
I have 2 array variables and I am trying to update a sharepoint list using both arrays.
Array 1 lets call Name
Array 2 lets call ID
The sharepoint list columns would be Date / Name / ID - So when updating this list I need the Name and ID to be on the same row.
I know how to update the list by using the create new item action using 1 array but it uses the currentitem() function not sure how to iterate through both arrays while still updating the same row in sharepoint.
Here's a pic of the flow but ofc the logic not what I want. I would like to update the sharepoint in 1 loop so data is created on the same rows and kept together from the 2 arrays.
enter image description here
See image for current method I have tried.
enter image description here
I have 2 compose object lists like so:
enter image description here
I need to link the location with the token. so combining the 2 arrays if possible into a json.
{
Location Name: XXXXX
Token: XXXX
}
{Location Name: XXXX
Token: XXXX
}
and so forth... doing this in power automate seems really hard as they seem to not allow you to do this easily.
I feel like I am close however I created a apply to each loop and for the input put the location names. Then I have to somehow call index 0 of the token array or... combine the 2 into a json object and call them both so they can be added to an excel table..
If you need more info let me know.. I just have tried a bunch of approach's and keep coming up short.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Assuming that both arrays have the same amount of items, you could iterate on one of the arrays and use a formula like this to get the values from the other array: variables('arrNames')[varriables('intIteration')] (init intIteration with 0 and increment it every time)

Yes both arrays have the same amount of elements. How do I perform the logic for doing what you suggest? Mostly the sytanx for the expressions is what I am missing. Also for the apply to each loop do I need to feed all variables to the input of it in order to use them inside the loop?

No, you only need to add one of the arrays to the loop. Use the other array in expressions as suggested in my answer above.
